# WCF Alternative for big messages

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, azure

I have a WCF Service deployed in azure. I have a client consuming this service which runs on Windows Phone 7. Everything worked fine but when i was trying to send to server some larger files or enumerables with lost of items, errors occured.  I found out that there can be configured max message size, max array length etc in configuration file. So i added few zeros to default values and it worked. However, i am not happy with this solution, because it is dirty.

my question is:

1.What exactly are disadvantages of mindlessly increasing message size limits and how does it affect service?

2.What is alternative for me instead of increasing message size?

In particular, i nedd to send to server GPS track which consists of same metadata and huge ammount of location points.

If i understand concept correctly, by default wcf uses SOAP, which is XML based. So objects sent are encoded as XML (similiar to XML serialization in .net?). So can it be somehow switched to some binary mode to send BLOBS or to upload large objects troyugh streams? Or is my oinly option to bypass WCF service completely and upload directly to server Storage (like SQL azure or Azure Blob Service), which exposes API to do so?

Thank you.

Comment: What you did is totally correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had quite same problem with huge gps tracks. I realy suggest not to use soap for this kind of tasks. You can use WebHttpBinding and implement streaming from your storage, or use something like ASP.NET WebAPI(will ship with MVC4 and can be hosted outside of IIS) for low level plumbing of streams to client. This will allow you to implement multiple download streams and all what you might need in this kind of tasks.

As in overall design concept of such systems, try not to think that one tool can solve your problems. Just use right took for a task. If you have some busines tasks - implement transactional ws-* based services for them. To transfer huge amount of data - use something like REST services. This will also help to query tracks.

For example: Tracks/{deviceid}/{trackDate}.{format}.

Feel free to ask=)

Answer (score 2):

As Peretz mentioned in a comment, that's what is supposed to happen.

The defaults are just that--**defaults**. Not "recommended" settings, nor pseudo-max sizes. They're available to alter based on your needs (and should be).

You *could* use net.tcp binding (if you're not already) which handles data a little better (with regards to serializing), but what you're doing is well within the boundary of WCF and its abilities.

Answer (score 0):

You should not arbitarily increase message sizes by chucking 0's on the end of these settings. Yes they are defaults which can be changed, but increasing message sizes whenever a limit is hit is not something you should always resort to. One of the reasons for having such small sizes is security: it prevents clients from flooding servers with huge messages and taking them down. It also encourages clients to send small messages which helps with scalability.

There are encodings that you can use: it depends on the bindings used. I thought that WCF encodes SOAP as binary anyway...but I may be wrong, I haven't touched WCF for 6 months now.

In previous projects whenever we hit size limits we looked at cutting our data into smaller chunks. One of the best things we ever did was implement pagable grids in our GUI's which only got 10-20 or so records from the sever at a time.  Entity Framework was greating in allowing us to write a single generic skip take query to do this for ALL of our grids.

Just increasing sizes is an easy fix...until you cant increase any further. Its a brittle and broken approach.